# (ricoh printer) scan to network shared folder

Tags: networking, printing, scanning

i have ricoh aficio mp c5000 and i was using a shared folder on my win 7 pc to scan to it,,
after upgrading to win 10 i have to create new account to solve some problems and then all the setting were rest

i managed to share a file and get the printer to see and connect to it ,, but still it gives me "transmission failed" after scanning

(if this help) i have another pc connected to the same network and it can access the same folder with the same user/pass entered in the printer setting and it can read/write on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i settled with creating a local ftp host using filezilla and connecting the printer to it